# Why is Apache Spark map() giving me a "not iterable" error?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Why is the following code, copied directly from Spark the Definitive Guide, returning an error?

```
df.select(map(col("Description"), col("InvoiceNo")).alias("complex_map"))\
  .selectExpr("complex_map['WHITE METAL LANTERN']").show(2)
```

Returns the following error:

> TypeError: Column is not iterable

I'm assuming newer releases of Spark have changed the behavior of this code, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to adjust for it to run.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the python [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function which is expecting second parameter to be iterable thus you get that error message.

What you're looking for is pyspark [`create_map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.create_map.html) function (which is the same as `map` in spark Scala API). Try this instead:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select(
    F.create_map(F.col("Description"), F.col("InvoiceNo")).alias("complex_map")
).select(
    F.col("complex_map")["WHITE METAL LANTERN"]
).show(2)
```